# How to make Django forms dynamic (with clickable fields and appearing fields)

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

In my Django project I have the following model:

models.py

```
class Paper(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     chapter_1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Intro')
     chapter_1_status = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=[('On','On'), ('Off','Off')], blank=True, null=True)
     chapter_1_description = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     chapter_1_word_count = models.IntegerField()
     chapter_1_reading_time = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
     chapter_2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Hypothesis')
     chapter_2_status = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=[('On','On'), ('Off','Off')], blank=True, null=True)
     chapter_2_description = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     chapter_2_word_count = models.IntegerField()
     chapter_2_reading_time = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
```

As you can see, apart from title and description all the other fields are repetitive (chapter 1, chapter 2, chapter 3 and so on till chapter 9 which is the maximum for the assigned Paper).

I'm using the field status to check whether that chapter will actually be included in the paper or not. If someone picks Off, the chapter won't be showed in the paper.

I now need to translate this concept into something more advanced: instead of having the regular Django form for this model, I would like to have a form where users see:

1. title
2. description
3. a list of the chapters available (intro, hypothesis...) and when they click on the specific chapter they want to include all the fields related to that chapter appear. All the chapters that do no get selected or clicked on should be treated as if the status was Off, so they should not show.

Right now, my forms.py looks like this:

```
class PaperFormClass(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PaperFormClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for field in iter(self.fields):
            self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({
                'class': 'form-control form-control-lg'
        })

    class Meta:
        model = Paper
        fields = '__all__'

class PaperForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Paper
        fields = '__all__'
```

How can I achieve a form that instead of displaying every field in model just displays title, description and a clickable list of all the chapters that can be included in the Paper? After the click on one chapter, the other fields related to that chapter should appear and be editable.

Thanks so much in advance for any suggestion that you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create another model `Chapter`

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
     paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper, related_name="chapters")
     chapter = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='1', choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1,10)])
     status = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=[('On','On'), ('Off','Off')], blank=True, null=True)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=1500)
     word_count = models.IntegerField()
     reading_time = models.DurationField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Then check for [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.inlines) show as inlines

Comment: Hi @itzMEonTV and thanks a lot for your answer. I've read the documentation linked and found it a bit confusing (I'm very new to Django). As far as you know, is there any other example that I could read to really make sure I understand the inlines process?